# Query rows modified in certain timespan

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to query only rows that were modified in a certain timespan?

The table in question is generated by Google Analytics, but it doesn't have an obvious way to query something like this (for example a last_modified timestamp or something smiliar).

Comment: what do you mean by "modified rows"? usually there are no "modified rows"

Comment: rows that were updated in a certain timespan.

Comment: BigQuery is an append-only technology, there is no update operation. All tables and Analytics exported tables are events, and these are rows added in the table, so each new context is a new row. Does this help?

Comment: oh I see, yes this helps! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, BigQuery does not have a concept of updated rows. It's append only.

If you want to get newly inserted rows for a given timespan, you could either use timestamps when inserting and query using that column, or use table decorators [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators